# How the kernel determines the process priority

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

Suppose four user processes are running in my system say P1, P2, P3, P4. Can the user understand which process is of least priority among others? How does the kernel prioritizes the processes? What are the parameters it takes into consideration while determining process priority?

I need this information since I'm trying to suspend one of the process which has least priority compared to others.

Answer (score 1):

Process priority is a not as simple as that and typically unless you do something, all user level process have the same priority to begin with (as they are time shared by scheduler).  However, you can instruct Kernel to either prioritize/de-prioritize a process by using a `nice` value per process.

For more details, take a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html